# Asynchronous API requests take longer to return results with several hundred loops - is the internet connection the bottleneck?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

I'm having some trouble finding the bottleneck in the code below. The purpose of the code is to send 400 API requests asynchronously in order to retrieve the data as quickly as possible.

The problem is that when I run the same code synchronously each request takes about 3 seconds, yet when I run it asynchronously the first responses take about 3 seconds but the response times get progressively longer with the last ones taking over 20 seconds.

I tried increasing my internet speed twice. The first time saw a significant improvement, but the second time saw hardly any increase at all. I spoke with the internet provider and they explained that increasing the speed is like adding lanes to a highway and that it will only benefit me if there's alot of other people using the same connection.

Am I stuck with this performance or is there a way to make this program run faster?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace ConsoleApplication___Alpha_Async_Download
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int iterations = 400;

        public static string[] content = new string[iterations];
        public static string[] URL = new string[iterations];

        public static int counter = 0;
        public static int[] count = new int[iterations];

        public static TimeSpan[] IndividualDownloadTime = new TimeSpan[iterations];
        public static DateTime[] IndividualDownloadTimeStampB = new DateTime[iterations];
        public static DateTime[] IndividualDownloadTimeStampA = new DateTime[iterations];

        public static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;

            Uri uri = new Uri("URL");
            ServicePoint sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(uri);
            sp.ConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to download data.");
            ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
            if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Data();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void Data()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading data...");
            Console.WriteLine();

            DateTime DownloadTimeStampA = DateTime.Now;

            System.Collections.Generic.List<Task> tasks = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Task>();
            for (int a = 0; a < iterations; a++)
            {
                var local = a;
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await DownloadDataAsync(local);
                }));
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine();
            DateTime DownloadTimeStampB = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan DownloadTime = DownloadTimeStampB - DownloadTimeStampA;
            Console.WriteLine("Download Time: " + DownloadTime.Minutes + ":" + DownloadTime.Seconds + ":" + DownloadTime.Milliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static async Task DownloadDataAsync(int c)
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
            count[c] = counter;

            char[] delimiters = new char[] { ',' };
            StreamReader URLs = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\URL_List.csv");
            string URLs2 = URLs.ReadLine();
            string[] list = URLs2.Split(',');
            List<string> URL = new List<string>(list);

            IndividualDownloadTimeStampA[c] = DateTime.Now;

            try
            {
                content[c] = await client.GetStringAsync(URL[c]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(count[c] + ". Error Message: " + ex);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            IndividualDownloadTimeStampB[c] = DateTime.Now;
            IndividualDownloadTime[c] = IndividualDownloadTimeStampB[c] - IndividualDownloadTimeStampA[c];
            Console.WriteLine(count[c] + "   Start: " + IndividualDownloadTimeStampA[c].ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "   Finish: " + IndividualDownloadTimeStampB[c].ToString("HH:mm:ss") + "   Duration: " + IndividualDownloadTime[c].Minutes + ":" + IndividualDownloadTime[c].Seconds + ":" + IndividualDownloadTime[c].Milliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're over-saturating the `ThreadPool` by running 400 tasks at once.  The increased delay is due to the pool being starved of available threads.

Comment: I ran the program using "https://postman-echo.com/delay/3" as a placeholder URL and the program ran in 6.5 seconds, even with the built-in 3 second delay. So I'm not sure why the other API takes so much longer. I contacted the other API provider and they said their latency is in microseconds, so I don't think its a problem on their end either. I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that the placeholder API isn't transferring as much data. But what can I do to speed it up?

Comment: Remove the `Task.Run`s. DownloadAsync is already a task - an I/O-based task even - you don't need to wrap in the threads used by Task.Run.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I made the change but unfortunately there was no improvement in performance. It is cleaner though without the Task.Run.

Comment: Do I need to upgrade my CPU maybe? Mine's a quad core with hyper-threading. Would a 16 core processor with hyper-threading quadruple the speed?

Comment: Assuming all the files you're downloading are from the same server, have you actually verified that the server is capable of serving files any faster? Maybe they throttle downloads from the same IP address? Or if their API is backed by a database, maybe the database can't give data to the web server any faster. Try writing a shell script that uses curl or wget to download all the files at the same time, and try downloading different files from different servers to verify it's not your code.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, the problem is due to `Task.Run`, which is unnecessary with I/O-bound code. Replace:

```
var local = a;
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
  await DownloadDataAsync(local);
}));
```

with:

```
tasks.Add(DownloadDataAsync(a));
```

Also, there's a lot of odd behavior in `DownloadDataAsync`; it looks like it's reading a CSV file *once per request*. It would be better to just load it in once and pass the specific URL to each invocation of `DownloadDataAsync`. There's also some copying to/from arrays and lists, which is not causing this issue but is inefficient and unnecessary.

Comment: Great suggestion, I made the first change but unfortunately there was no improvement in performance. It still took about 28 seconds to run. I'll definitely make the suggestion regarding the CSV file as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that your configuration for ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit is too aggressive, I understand you tried this to get better performance but you must set a reasonable limit on this setting or you will run into another potential issues in the tcp/ip stack.

You are hitting an issue in the ThreadPool to get the performance your are looking for, you can use next code to improve your performance:

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
   ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(200, 200);

These settings will cause the ThreadPool to allow more threads to be created faster, and to have more async completion ports, limiting as well the number of max threads that will try do concurrent work at any time, right now you are getting throttled and this is why you are not getting better performance, specifically by the MaxThreads setting, this is how is explained in .Net documentation:

> ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(Int32, Int32) Method
>
> Sets the number of requests to the thread pool that can be active
>   concurrently. All  requests above that number remain queued until
>   thread pool threads become available.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately though there was no improvement in performance. I took your advice and lowered the ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit to 40. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: if expanding the number of concurrent threads able to do work does not help most likely the issue is not in the client but the server side, probably there is a limit there for the number of concurrent calls from a single IP, this is a typical scenario for services to prevent DoS attacks, the limitations could be number of concurrent connections or bandwith per IP address. check it.